# Define an anonymous function as part of an object definition?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have:

```
var myfunc = function() {
   // do stuff
}
myfunc.foo = function() {
      //do other stuff
};
```

Now `myfunc` has a property `foo` that is a function, great. Is there a way to create `myfunc` from the get-go in this state? That is, I want `foo` to be defined when `myfunc` is created. The syntax, I would imagine, is something like:

```
var myfunc = {
  :function() {
     // do stuff
  }, 
  foo: function() {
     // do other stuff
  }
}
```

Except that's wrong.

Comment: You're misunderstanding `this`.

Comment: I do that a lot, sorry. See edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery:

```
var myFunc = jQuery.extend(
    function() { ... },
    {
        bar: "wioll haven be",
        foo: function() { alert(myFunc.bar); }
    }
);

myFunc();
myFunc.foo();
```

Comment: +1 for actually answering the question properly. Now just offer a non-jQuery alternative!

Comment: @Raynos: Just rewrite or steal `jQuery.extend`.

Comment: @SLaks jQuery.extend is a really big powerful beast. It does too much. You don't need all of it. It's like 100 lines to copy!

Comment: jQuery is OK. I'm surprised that this is something that can't be done syntactically.

Comment: I commented out the jQuery source for brevity.

Comment: Why does/should jQuery have anything to do with this?  Downvoted.

Comment: @Spacemoses: To avoid rewriting `jQuery.extend`.

Answer (score 3):

You can place an anonymous function inside an object, however the only plausible way of doing this is to call the anonymous function when the object is initialised, otherwise the function will never be able to be called - it's anonymous!

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g105b/99K5F/

```
var myfunc = function() {
    this.foo = function() {
        console.log("myfunc.foo called!");
    };

    (function() {
        console.log("Anonymous function called.");
    })();
};

// Initialising "myfunc" will call the anonymous function.
var instance = new myfunc();

// Now the foo method can be called.
instance.foo();
```

Answer (score 3):

A little confused as to what functionality you are looking to gain here...

If you want some code to execute when the myfunc is defined, you could use the module pattern:

```
var myfunc = (function() {
    var self = {};

    // any initialization code can go here
    alert("myfunc init code");

    self.somePublicMethod = function () {

    }

    return self;

}());
```

This can also be called an immediate function, a function that is defined and executed at the same time.

From within the closure, and code that is not defined as part of another function will be executed when the object is defined, so when you do something like this:

```
myfunc.somePublicMethod()
```

the alert would have already been fired.

Comment: Although I accepted another answer.. +1, the module pattern works for what I was doing (though not exactly) without using extend.

Answer (score 2):

(This answer written before the first half of the question was significantly revised)

> Now myfunc has a property `foo` that is a function

No, it doesn't.

You called it with `myfunc()` so `this` is a reference to the global `window` object, thus you are creating `window.foo`.

Possibly what you are looking for is:

```
function myfunc () {
    // do stuff when myfunc is called
}
myfunc.foo = function () {
    // do stuff when myfunc.foo is called
};
```

or perhaps:

```
function myfunc () {
    // do stuff when myfunc is instantiated
    this.foo = function () {
        // Add a foo property to this when myfunc is instantiated
        // ... which is only worth while if you are doing pretty 
        // ... odd stuff with the variables that are passed in 
    }
}
var instance = new myfunc();
```

or maybe:

```
function myfunc () {
    // do stuff when myfunc is instantiated
}
myfunc.prototype.foo = function () {
    // Have a foo function on every instance of myfunc
}
var instance = new myfunc();
```

… but you've abstracted the problem you are trying to solve away in your question, so it is hard to tell what you are actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly code acrobatics, this is probably the closest you'll get:

```
var myfunc;
(myfunc = function(){}).foo = function(){};
```

There is no practical difference in declaring methods later though, since javascript is single-threaded.

Comment: I agree - it was really more an academic question, in that I wanted to learn something about the syntax if it was there to learn.